# shift+enter is not working in textarea

Tags: textarea, newline, enter, shift

I tried several codes but still, it's not working.

```
$(".chatboxtextarea").on('keypress', function(e){

  if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey){

    $('#file_name #fileLoader').show();
    console.log('loader div triggered!');

    if($.trim($(this).val()).length > 0){

      if ((entr === false) && (submt === false)) {
        sendMessageClient();
        entr = true;
      }

    }else{
         $(this).focus();
    }

  }

});
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve. Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: shift+enter is not working .after click on it form will submit. I tried StackOverflow codes. but still, it's not working.

Comment: `if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)` means "if key is enter and shift not pressed"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the creating of a new line from happening you can use the following code:

```
$("textarea").keydown(function(e){

    // Enter was pressed without shift key
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey)
    {
        // prevent default behavior
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[(Copy paste from here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5842813/how-can-i-only-allow-shiftenter-to-return-new-line-in-text-area)

This will prevent the default behaviour from happening when pressing enter (but not pressing shift at the same time) inside a textarea.

Also, [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Su5ts/) is mentioned in the answer.

Comment: thanks . enter is working properly. but after the click ( shift+enter ) it's not creating a new line.